# ¿Como eliminar los espacios en blanco en un string?

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo eliminar los espacios en blanco en un string? ¿Cómo puedo juntar todos los caracteres y eliminar esos espacios ?

```js
var incognita = "Hola como estas";
```

Answer (score 23):

Puedes utilizar String.replace() asi:

```js
var incognita = "Hola como estas"
console.log(incognita.replace(/ /g, ""));
```

Comment: una consulta que significa / /g , gracias.

Comment: Para responderte, la parte `/ ` significa que es una exprecion regultar que busca espacios, y la `/g` significa que es global, es decir busca todos los espacios en la variable. Por ejemplo `var h = 'Hola_Mundo_';  h.replace(/_/g,'');` es igual a `HolaMundo`

Answer (score 3):

Sí quieres hacer el replace desde el html esta es una forma de como hacerlo. 
en este caso uso un enlace
HTML:

```
<a href="/dsoftware/{{item.id_proyecto}}/{{item.nombre | replacepipe}}">Enlace</a>
```

PIPE (crear nuevo archivo 'replace.pipe.ts'):

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'replacepipe'
})
export class ReplacePipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: string): string {
        var re = / /gi; 
        var newstr = value.replace(re, "-"); 
        return newstr;
      }

}
```

MODULE:

```
import { ReplacePipe } from './replace.pipe';
...

declarations:[AppComponent, ... , ReplacePipe 
]
```

Answer (score -5):

```
var incognita = "Hola como estas";
console.log(incognita.trim()); // Output: Holacomoestas
```

Tiene más información sobre el método trim aquí:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/Trim

Comment: Lo que planteas es **incorrecto**. `trim()` lo que produce es que se remuevan los espacios al inicio y al final de la cadena, no los que se encuentran entre medio

Comment: El método `trim()` elimina espacios en blanco al principio y final de una cadena, pero no los que se encuentren por el medio. El resultado sería "Hola como estas" no "Holacomoestas"  que es lo que se pide