# Quitar espacios en blanco en un query golang

Tags: mysql, go

Deseo quitar los posibles espacios en blanco en un query mysql ya que armo un archivo de texto el cual no debe tener espacios en blanco al principio y final de la cadena

```
count := len(columns)
values := make([]interface{}, count)
valuePtrs := make([]interface{}, count)
for i := range values {
    valuePtrs[i] = &values[i]
}

for rows.Next() {
    err := rows.Scan(valuePtrs...)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    concat := make([]string, 0)
    for i, _ := range columns {
        val := values[i]

        b, ok := val.([]byte)
        if ok {
            concat = append(concat, string(b))
        } else {
            concat = append(concat, fmt.Sprintf("%v", val))
        }
    }
    line := strings.Join(concat, "|")
    _, err = f.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("%s\n", line)))
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: puedes mirarte esta solución:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/165669/como-eliminar-los-espacios-en-blanco-en-un-string/165672

Answer (score 1):

Existe un metodo dentro de Strings llamado trimSpace que probablemente te valga para lo que necesitas.

```
func TrimSpace(s string) string
```

Te dejo un par de links con información ampliada:

https://pkg.go.dev/strings#TrimSpace

https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.5:src/strings/strings.go;l=867